# SSRS - generating blank slide, when exporting to PPT

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I'm working on report in SQL Server Data Tools. I've got 2 Datasets (Tablixes) that can be generated in Excel / PPT. When I generate the report into Excel, there are no issues, but when I generate it to PPT, it generates me blank slides after every data slides. The strange thing is that it does only for 1st Tablix, for the 2nd one, it generates everything without any blank slides. The red line on the screen divides end of 1st data sets and 2nd datasets:

[image]

I thought that the trigger is in wider canvas, but the wide of both datasets are the same:

[image]

Could you share any ideas, how to avoid generating blank slides, please?

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to make sure you don't have any page breaks, either after the first tablix or before the second tablix.

Comment: @BJones thanks, but I've tried it also and still those blank pages appear :(